# Are the elements of the Cartesian product of $A\times A$ (or $A^2$) the same elements of those in $A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Are the elements of the Cartesian product of $A\times A$ (or $A^2$) the same elements of those in $A$?

I want to know if it is just the combination of the "doubled" elements of the set $A$ or just the same, repeated elements. Basically, is the cross product of $A$ and $A$ an identity?

Comment: $A \times A$ is made up of pairs of elements in $A$.

Comment: So if Set A consisted of elements {2,1} the elements of the cross product would be {2,1} {2,2} {1,1}?

Comment: The pairs are ordered, so $\{1,2\}\times\{1,2\} = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in the cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$ are just ordered pairs of elements with the first component in the set $A$ and the second one in the set $B$; i.e.
$$
A\times B = \{(x,y):x\in A,y\in B\}
$$

For example, let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ an $B=\{4,5\}$. Then, the elements of $A \times B$ are
$$
A\times B =\{(1,4),(1,5),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5)\}
$$

So, if you want to study $A\times A$, you have the following set:
$$
A\times A = \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}
$$

Note that they are **ordered** pairs, so $(1,2)\neq(2,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

For a given set $A$,
$$ A\times A:=\{(x,y):x,y\in A\}$$
That is, it is the set of ordered pairs of elements, where the element in each "slot" comes from the set $A$.